# AngularJS - Error while manually using injector to inject a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I encounter an issue when trying to manually use angular.injector to inject a service which is opening a dialog, which in turn, uses inside it's template a directive, which uses a dynamic template.

The errors I have in the console are:

> 1: Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <-       $anchorScroll <- ngIncludeDirective <- $location
>
> 2: Controller 'ngInclude', required by directive 'ngInclude', can't be found!

Here is the [plunker demonstrating the problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/oVJMqt?p=preview)

```
var customSvc = angular.injector(['ng', 'pluginApp']).get("customSvc");
customSvc.testOpenDialog(100, scope);
```

I also tried building the url and specifying it as a directive attribute and accessing it from the templateUrl function, but also in this case it fails, because the value I receive is just the name of the variable, not the content.

If I avoid injection of the service via angular.injector, the code works, however due to the nature of the application I can't avoid it, besides, I am interested in understanding what is the behind reason of this error, if anyone is kind enough to shed some light into the matter.

Comment: You want to access "customSvc" service in your directive, right?

Comment: I already access it via angular.injector function and it works, the problem is  in the sampleDirective, because over there, ng-include is not working

Comment: In sampleDirective, why you are using ng-include in template, and the file you are including don't have extension?template: "<div ng-include='sampleLinkTemplate'></div>" , use templareUrl:"sampleLinkTemplate.html"

Comment: Because it uses the value of the variable from the scope which is set in the link function. It's a way of using "dynamic template" based on a variable present in the scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to inject the service in the following way:

```
   var customSvc = angular.injector(['ng', 'pluginApp', 
      function($provide) {
        var $rootElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));
        $provide.value('$rootElement', $rootElement);
      }]).get("customSvc");
```

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LHxAcU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In your, `gedContextMenu.js` file, do following changes

Inject `pluginApp`

```
angular.module('gedContextMenuApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.popover','pluginApp']);
```

Inject service `customSvc` in your `gedContextMenu` menu directive,

```
angular.module('gedContextMenuApp').directive('gedContextMenu',['$log','$templateCache', '$uibModal', 'customSvc', function($log, $templateCache, $uibModal, customSvc) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      gedContextData: '='
    },
    template: "<button class='fa fa-cog' bs-popover data-template='{{popoverTemplate}}' data-auto-close='1' data-placement='bottom' data-animation='am-flip-x'></button>",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.popoverTemplate = 'popoverTemplate.html';

      $scope.executePlugin = function($event, contextItem) {
        var propName = contextItem.action;
        $scope.contextItem = contextItem;
        $log.info('property name ' + propName + ' used to trigger event ', $event.type);
        $scope[propName] = $event;
      }

      $scope.click = function($event, contextItem) {
        $scope.executePlugin($event, contextItem);
      }
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('openDialog', function(event) {
        if (event && event.type === 'click') {
          console.log(customSvc);
          // var customSvc = angular.injector(['ng', 'pluginApp']).get("customSvc");

          //angular.injector(['ng', function($provide) {
          //  var $rootElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));
          //  $provide.value('$rootElement', $rootElement);
          //}]).invoke(function($injector) {
          //  var localRootElement = $injector.get('$rootElement');
          //});

          // customSvc.testOpenDialog(100, scope);
          //customSvc.testDirettivaConfirm(100, scope);

        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, if I bypass the manual use of the injector, it works, but I can't do that in my app because actions.js is loaded dynamically and I don't know at the gedContextMenu directive level what services it will use or not use. The plunker I posted was just a simplification of the problem. Regardless, I still need to make it work with manual use of angular.injector or understand if it's not possible due to some limitations